# List the names of all married employees and their spouses who are assigned to the “East London Crossing” project

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

```
Project   Table Pk(project Number)
```

[image: Project Table]

```
 Marriage Table : PK (EmployeeNumber)
 Fk_ Marriage - employee (spouseNumber)
```

[image: Marriage Table]

```
Employee Table (EmployeeNumber)
```

[image: Employee Table]

```
Workon Table : PK(EmployeeNumber,ProjectNumber,CityCode) 
              FK_ Workon - employee (EmployeeNumber)
              FK_ Workon - project (projectNumber)
```

[image: Workon Table]

```
1 Table : Project  pk(project Number)
2 Table : Marriage PK (EmployeeNumber) 
          Fk_ Marriage - employee (spouseNumber)
3 Table : Employee(EmployeeNumber) 
4 Table : Workon PK(EmployeeNumber,ProjectNumber,CityCode) 
          FK_ Workon - employee (EmployeeNumber)
          FK_ Workon - project (projectNumber)

   List the names of all married employees and their spouses who are assigned to the “East London Crossing” project
```

it is possible with join or we need to do more than join to love problem

Comment: don't post image  ... post text sample

Comment: Can you please add what you've tried so far?

Comment: yes . is possible with join  ..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve this problem using Joins - in fact, since the components you wish to retrieve are in separate tables, a Join will typically be necessary.

You will need to join the Project table with the Employee tables and Workon tables. The Marriage table is essentially irrelevant since its information is already present in the Employee table. In SQL, this is a cartesian product (FROM) where certain constraints are enforced/selected (WHERE).

For example (assuming both the husband and wife are both working on the ELC):

```
SELECT E1.FirstName, E1.LastName, E2.FirstName, E2.LastName 
FROM Project P, Workon W1, Workon W2, Employee E1, Employee E2
WHERE P.projectNumber = W1.projectNumber AND P.projectNumber = W2.projectNumber AND
    W1.employeeNumber = E1.EmployeeNumber AND W2.employeeNumber = E2.EmployeeNumber AND
    E1.SpouseNumber = E2.EmployeeNumber AND P.name = "East London Crossing";
```

(Note: I haven't actually tested this code so it may have syntax errors)

Alternatively, you could choose to use Natural Joins, in which case tables such as Project and Workon can be joined together (e.g. `Project NATURAL JOIN Workon`).

Comment: I wouldn't use implicit or natural joins (ever)

Comment: An implicit join is essentially a Left Join though afaik?

Comment: Comma/implicit join is cross join with lower precedence than keyword/explicit joins. That's inner join on true & left join on true.

Comment: @AndrewFan i got correct output .is it optimize way to do . or we have other way   to do ??

Comment: Your DBMS will perform basic query optimization on all queries you give it, breaking it down into its constituent parts and choosing the best execution plan for a given query.

Answer (score 0):

You need  the use for table workon and employee  twice of join both the id

```
SELECT e1.FirstName
    , e1.LastName
    , e2.FirstName
    , e2.LastName 
FROM Project p
INNER JOIN  Workon w1 ON  p.projectNumber = w1.projectNumber 
INNER JOIN Workon W2 ON p.projectNumber = W2.projectNumber 
INNER JOIN Employee e1 ON  w1.employeeNumber = e1.EmployeeNumber
INNER JOIN Employee e2 ON W2.employeeNumber = e2.EmployeeNumber  
    AND e1.SpouseNumber = e2.EmployeeNumber
WHERE p.id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Fan i modified your code how good it is

```
SELECT E.EmployeeNumber,E.FirstName, E.LastName,
       E.SpouseNumber, w.projectNumber,P.name
       FROM Project P, Workon W, Employee E 
       WHERE P.projectNumber = W.projectNumber AND
             W.employeeNumber = E.EmployeeNumber  
             AND P.name = "East London Crossing" AND 
                 E.SpouseNumber is not NULL;
```